# How to gloss a word that doesn't contribute semantically?

Tags: interlinear-gloss

I'm trying to fix a gloss where I've been told not to include a literal translation of a word. I know it's a linkage marker, but I don't know which word to 'call' it.

> emu da ballà
> we.are from dance.INF
> 'We will dance'

The problem word is "da", which literally means "from". I need to annotate it as "LKG", but how do I represent this in the sentence without putting "from"?

EDIT:
The instruction I was given was:

> Even though it means 'from' literally, it does not in this construction: please replace with LKG (for linkage marker)

Presumably you can't write LKG on its own? So just "from.LKG"?

My larger question is whether you would always use a literal translation for a word even when it's used in a specific context.

For example in French, "à" and "de" loosely mean to/from, but both can be translated as "to" before an infinitive:

> Il m'aide à cuisiner
> he to.me=helps to cook.INF
> He helps me to cook
>
> Il me demande de cuisiner
> he to.me=asks from cook.INF
> He asks me to cook

Is it correct to write "from" in the second gloss, because the preposition is "de" and not "à"?

Comment: I have a similar problem with PIE glosses. The gloss "with" biases understanding. It also helps, because I need a reasonable mnemonic. I translate the gloss to German, consider the German etymology, translate that again, and suddenly gloss the original root as "uber"; I also know that the root is reflected as *kei* in Greek, which is glossed "and". So I have two and a half glosses to work with. The problem is much worse if working in only one language, if "with" means just that. However for particles and morphemes one ```3rd p sg``` *indicate* ```pl Noun``` *definition* when glossing sentences

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't gloss it as "from".

Comment: EDIT: updated original post with the instructions I was given

Comment: Who has the authority to tell a linguist how to mark a gloss? And why should you pay any attention to such instructions? Glosses are not official. They are short, informative, and useful, but they're throwaways. Short answer: use whatever you think works best.

Comment: Why do you say "Presumably you can't write LKG on its own"?

Comment: I'm relatively novice at this. @ColinFine Are you saying in a gloss you can write the annotation on its own? we.are LKG dance.INF ?

Comment: Why not? When a word in an utterance has only functional meaning, why write anything but its function? I've no experience of glossing myself, but picking a journal at random from my shelf I find a gloss "IsInd Aux Deic sing-IsCmp1Sb" (Newman, Stanley, _Functional Changes in the Salish Pronominal System_, IJAL 46:3. 1980). _Sing_ is the only semantic item in that gloss - the rest are all functional.

Comment: @jlawler, the folks in Leipzig seem to have that authority. An editor may or may not be a stickler for following the conventions, which gives one a basis for judging "why should I". Sassing the editor (or instructor) is one approach, saying "No, you are mistaken about the conventions".

Comment: You didn't say it was an editor. Questions like this usually come from students following a local teacher's idiosyncracies. If you're being published, the editor probly has a house style sheet to follow; consult them for details and principles, if any.

Answer (score 3):

In a gloss, you can mark an element with an annotation without a label or literal translation of the word.

In this example, the word "da" is functional and not lexical, therefore it is appropriate to annotate it as "LKG" (linkage marker) without literally translating it as "from". So the answer is:

> emu da ballà
>   we.are LKG dance.INF
>   'We will dance'

Comment: optimally you allign the corresponding symbols above each other for visual accessability